# How to apply css only to clicked menu wehn menu click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

```
<div id="schedulelist" class="list-group">
         <label class="sclist" for="sclist">List</label>
         <input id="sclist" type="checkbox">
         <c:forEach items="${datelist}" var="list" varStatus="status" >
             <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active py-3 lh-tight"
                aria-current="true">
                 <div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center justify-content-between">
                     <strong class="mb-1">${"Day"} ${status.count}</strong>
                     <small>${list}</small>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-10 mb-1 small">${city.name}</div>
             </a>
         </c:forEach>
     </div>
```

Above is my code. When 1day is clicked, I want to change the background color corresponding to 1day's div to red.

And when 2day is clicked, I want to return the color of 1day back to blue and change the background color to red only for 2day.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+OR+css+change+background+color+click+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.
Post RENDERED HTML and not server code

Comment: The  best answer will have delegate or delegation in it

Comment: Would you rather do this via JavaScript or HTML/CSS only?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this

CSS could be this

```
#schedulelist a strong:active { background-color: red }
```

and you could use checkboxes too in combination with the + selector.

Here I use JavaScript

```js
const schedulelist = document.getElementById("schedulelist");
const items = schedulelist.querySelectorAll("a strong")
const activate = e => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  items.forEach(item => item.classList.remove("active"));
  if (tgt.tagName==="STRONG") tgt.classList.add("active");
};
schedulelist.addEventListener("click",activate)
//schedulelist.addEventListener("mouseover",activate)
```

```css
#schedulelist a strong { background-color: blue }
/* #schedulelist a strong:active { background-color: red } */
#schedulelist a strong.active { background-color: red }
```

```html
<div id="schedulelist" class="list-group">
  <label class="sclist" for="sclist">List</label>
  <input id="sclist" type="checkbox">

  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active py-3 lh-tight" aria-current="true">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center justify-content-between">
      <strong class="mb-1">1</strong>
      <small>list</small>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10 mb-1 small">A</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active py-3 lh-tight" aria-current="true">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center justify-content-between">
      <strong class="mb-1">2</strong>
      <small>list</small>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10 mb-1 small">B</div>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active py-3 lh-tight" aria-current="true">
    <div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center justify-content-between">
      <strong class="mb-1">3</strong>
      <small>list</small>
    </div>
    <div class="col-10 mb-1 small">C</div>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: I want to apply css to a tag, how do I change it?

Comment: I do that. I apply the class to the tag and the css can be whatever you want